# Extract amount in cents from currency within text

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Suppose I have arbitrary text with a currency value in it, like this:

```
The price today is $1,234.56! Don't miss out!
```

I want to extract the number of cents as an `int`, ie:

```
123456
```

Some criteria:

- The 000's comma is optional
- The price is less than $1,000,000.00
- The `$` is always there
- The decimal part is always there

I have tried using Pattern and Matcher, but it seems all too messy.

What is the simplest code that will do this?

Comment: is `$` sign always there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this single line, which includes the parse to int, is about as terse as it can be:

```
int cents = Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll(".*\\$((\\d+),)?(\\d+)\\.(\\d+).*", "$2$3$4"));
```

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev good enough to vote for the question too? :)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
    String s = "The price today is $1,234.56! Don't miss out!";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$(((\\d+,?\\d++)|(\\d++))\\.?\\d\\d)");  
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    m.find();
    Long cents = Long.parseLong(m.group(1).replaceAll("[,.]", ""));
    System.out.println(cents);
```

prints

```
123456
```

Comment: And to then convert the value "$1,234.56" to cents, just strip out all non-numeric characters with `value.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" )`

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question. How is `$1,234.56` the number of cents? Or `1234.56`?